# C#: How would you cycle through items in a listview using next and previous buttons?

Tags: c#

C#: How would you cycle through items in a listview using next and previous buttons?

Background:

Let's say you have 10 items in a listview.

Next to the listview there are two buttons titled previos and next.

Problem:

How would you cycle through those listview items after clicking the Next and or Previous button?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to select the next item (so with items a, b, c, go from b selected to c selected), you can do this:

```
        if (listView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            int oldSelection = listView.SelectedIndices[0];
            listView.SelectedIndices.Clear();

            if (oldSelection + 1 >= listView.Items.Count)
                listView.SelectedIndices.Add(0);
            else
                listView.SelectedIndices.Add(oldSelection + 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying that you want to implement paging?

If so, just keep a record of your current page number in index and when the next button is clicked, increment the page number, retrieve that page's worth of records and bind that to the list.

There is an automatic way of doing this if you implement data providers and such. Check the documentation on ListView on how this is done. You will need to give the button a special "Action" for it to work.

For more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515102.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
int oldSelection = ListView1.SelectedIndices[0];

if(*NextOptionSelected* && oldSelection + 1 < ListView1.Items.Count)
{
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection + 1].Selected = true;
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection + 1].Focused = true;
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection].Selected = false;
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection].Focused = false;
}
else if(*LastOptionSelected* && oldSelection > 0)
{
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection - 1].Selected = true;
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection - 1].Focused = true;
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection].Selected = false;
     ListView1.Items[oldSelection].Focused = false;
}

ListView1.EnsureVisible(ListView1.SelectedIndices[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//UpOrDown is a +1 or -1
void Page(int UpOrDown){
    //Determine if something is selected
    if (listView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
        {
            int oldIndex = listView.SelectedIndices(0);
            listView.SelectedIndices.Clear();

            //Use mod!
            int numberOfItems = listView.Items.Count();
            listView.SelectedIndices.Add((oldIndex + UpOrDown) % numberOfItems)
        }
}
```

Using `modulus` division, I feel like people have forgot about this guy

Comment: When navigating up from zero, then the mod won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**put +1 for next and -1 for prev data** 
here is the code:-

```
Dim CurrentRow As Integer
CurrentRow = Form2.ListView1.Items.IndexOf(Form2.ListView1.FocusedItem)
CurrentRow =CurrentRow + 1
Form2.ListView1.Items(CurrentRow).Selected = True
Form2.ListView1.Items(CurrentRow).Focused = True
```

This is the vb code to move to the next row in listview
1.Add the listview control to form
2.Add one button to form
3.Double click that button and right the above code

Comment: If you want to goto to the next row write the above code in your button and change the 3rd line
    CurrentRow=CurrentRow +1
or else if you want to goto your prev data change the third line to
    CurrentRow=CurrentRow -1
That's all my frnd

Answer (score 0):

tested aproach using Page method, null/out of index range-proof:

```
private void Page(int UpOrDown, ListView list)
        {
            //Determine if something is selected
            list.Focus();
            if (list.SelectedIndices.Count == 0)
            {
                if (list.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    list.Items[0].Selected = true;
                    list.SelectedIndices.Add(0);
                    list.Items[0].Focused = true;
                    list.EnsureVisible(list.Items[0].Index);
                    list.TopItem = list.Items[0];
                }
            }
            if (list.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
            {
                if (list.SelectedIndices[0] == null)
                {
                    list.SelectedIndices.Add(0);
                }
                int oldIndex = list.SelectedIndices[0];
                list.SelectedIndices.Clear();

                //Use mod!
                int numberOfItems = list.Items.Count;
                if (oldIndex + UpOrDown >= 0 && oldIndex + UpOrDown <= list.Items.Count-1)
                {
                    list.SelectedIndices.Add((oldIndex + UpOrDown)%numberOfItems);
                    list.SelectedItems[0].Selected = true;
                    list.SelectedItems[0].Focused = true;
                    list.EnsureVisible(list.SelectedItems[0].Index);
                    //list.TopItem = list.SelectedItems[0];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Without testing it, I'm guessing this would work:

```
 for(int i=0;i<listView.Items.Count;i++)
      listView.Items[i]
```